# A synonym for the word "pursuing" in the following context

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym for the word "pursuing" in the following context:

> "At present, I'm ***pursuing*** my third year of business studies"

Comment: Not strictly (or perhaps even loosely) a synonym, but 'in' works (and sounds less highfalutin).

Comment: Please share why you don't like `pursuing` and what properties the synonym should have to fulfil your requirements.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any problem with using of "pursuing". But I'm not English native speaker and that's why it's difficult for me to understand the accurate meaning and translate it into my language. Normally, I use to see the word "purse" about the people that escape from the police by cars on the autostrada  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sense of **pursue** in your example seems to be [sense 1.2 from Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pursue). (*Seek to attain or accomplish (a goal) over a long period*)

The synonyms listed for this sense are:

> strive for, push towards, work towards, try for, seek, search for, quest (after), be intent on, aim at/for, have as a goal, have as an objective, aspire to

If those don't work for you, you could always go with '**in**', as Edwin suggested.

Comment: Thank you Area for your comment. 
Please let me know what you think about when you hear the following sentence: ""At present, I'm pursuing my third year of business studies" 

You presented some different meanings (3), but what do you think it's probably the main meaning?

Comment: @Dory: Pursue(sense 1.2) is used for a lot of things, and these synonyms will hold good for many of those cases. However, in the context of an academic degree, using pursue is idiomatic and easily understood. I don't think you should replace it with any other word.